# how to open files using a for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, file, class

So the purpose of this function is to test all the files in my files folder. I want to iterate through the for loop and test each and every single file but my problem is my return statement only returns the last file for testing. I need it to go through all the files and return an answer for each file, not just one. I am very confused and I am a beginner programmer so any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

here is my defined function:

```
def testFileOpener():
    files = ['maze.txt','maze50100.txt','maze1020.txt','maze510nosoln.txt','maze510islandnosoln.txt','maze510island.txt','maze510cycles.txt','maze510.txt']
        
    for file in files:
        try:
            print(f'Testing {file}\n')
            f = open(file)
            mazeFiles = f.readlines()
            
        except:
            print('This File Does Not Exist.')

            
    f.close()
    return mazeFiles
```

My test function looks like this:

```
def test():
    mazeFiles = testFileOpener()
    m = Maze(mazeFiles)
    m.gridAssembly()
    m.solver(0,0,None)
    m.tester()
```

output is supposed to look like:

Testing maze.txt

-This line of code should be the returning the lines of each of maze.txt-

Testing maze50100.txt

-This line of code should be the returning the lines of each of maze50100.txt-

... Each file is passed into the tester which tests the mazeFiles so in each instance mazeFiles must be a different '.txt' file

etc... until we get to the last file but for some reason it gets to the last file and mazeFiles only returns that specific files lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I tried:

```
def testFileOpener():
    files = ['maze.txt','maze50100.txt','maze1020.txt','maze510nosoln.txt','maze510islandnosoln.txt','maze510island.txt','maze510cycles.txt','maze510.txt']
    random = []   
    for file in files:
        
        print(f'Testing {file}\n')
        with open(file) as f:
            d = f.readlines()
            random.append(d)
    for i in random:
        mazeFiles = i
    return mazeFiles
```

Comment: You should close the file where you open it: in the loop.

Comment: hey, @DYZ it still will only return the last files lines

Comment: As @DYZ said, you need to close the file in the loop, not in the end. Also have a look at the "with" statement, which handles closing automatically:
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python

Comment: Also you overwrite mazeFiles in the loop. You need to add to a list, otherwise you only end up with the last.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen I tried implementing a list but it still only returns the last selection, did you get it to work on your end?

Comment: Please edit your code to show what you tried

Comment: @OneCricketeer Just edited it thanks for reminding me

Comment: 1) `random` is a python module name, so best not to name a list variable that 2) `for i in random` is not needed 3) you're still not returning the list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a function that logically returns a number of results you can form it into a generator where each result you send out with a `yield` instead of a `return`. so your code could look like this:

```
def testFileOpener():
    files = ['maze.txt','maze50100.txt','maze1020.txt','maze510nosoln.txt','maze510islandnosoln.txt','maze510island.txt','maze510cycles.txt','maze510.txt']
    for file in files:
        print(f'Testing {file}\n')
        with open(file) as f:
            d = f.readlines()
            yield d # note that you can actually just `yield f` if you deal with each one sequentially
                    # since the file only gets closed after the next iteration
                    # this is one of the benefits of using a generator.
```

Then the caller of this function would probably want to iterate over the results:

```
def test():
    for mazeFiles in testFileOpener():
        m = Maze(mazeFiles)
        m.gridAssembly()
        m.solver(0,0,None)
        m.tester()
```

Comment: this works amazing I just have a question what exactly does that yield operand do?

Comment: the formal definition is [in PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/#specification-yield) although some of the implementation has changed since then, the main part is _"If a yield statement is encountered, the state of the function is frozen, and the value [is sent to for loop]. By "frozen" we mean that all local state is retained, including [implementation details]: enough information is saved so that the next time .next() is invoked, the function can proceed exactly as if the yield statement were just another external call."_

Comment: and more detail in a less technical spec and more usable wiki format can be found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Again this was written for python2 so a few of the lower level details are slightly different but the way the generator is written is identical.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you only want the `testFileOpener` to load one file. If that is the case, the simplest solution is relocate your list to the `test` function

```
def testFileOpener(fname):
   try:
        print(f'Testing {fname}\n')
        with open(fname) as f:
            return f.readlines()
   except:
        print(f"File {fname} does not exist")
    
def test():
    files = ['maze.txt','maze50100.txt','maze1020.txt','maze510nosoln.txt','maze510islandnosoln.txt','maze510island.txt','maze510cycles.txt','maze510.txt']
    for f in files:
        mazeFiles = testFileOpener(f)
        m = Maze(mazeFiles)
        m.gridAssembly()
        m.solver(0,0,None)
        m.tester()
```

Otherwise, you need to append each `readlines` result to a list, then actually return that list. But, that would result in unnecessary memory usage, so best to only test one file at a time